# Why some apps can't be moved to the sd card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card

I know that the developer chooses to **allow** that or not via the `android:installLocation” attribute` in the manifest. My question is: What are the reasons to allow that or not?

---

I often see many apps that don't fall in any of catregories of the next list. They don't allow moving to the sd card, why they would do that? What type of advantage/benefit could that give.

> - Services
> - Alarm Services
> - Input Method Engines
> - Live Wallpapers
> - App Widgets
> - Account Managers
> - Sync Adapters
> - Device Administrators
> - Broadcast Receivers listening for "boot completed"

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot

Comment: Have you read the documentation for installLocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot), you should not allow your app to be installed on external storage in the following cases:

> - Services
> - Alarm Services
> - Input Method Engines
> - Live Wallpapers
> - App Widgets
> - Account Managers
> - Sync Adapters
> - Device Administrators
> - Broadcast Receivers listening for "boot completed"

The documentation goes on to say:

> By default, the system will not allow your application to install on the external storage, so you don't need to worry about your existing applications.

This means that the default case is to not allow installation on external storage. That may mean that a large percentage of apps that are not installable on external storage are simply cases of the developer being unaware of `installLocation` at all and using the default behavior.

You'd need to analyze each app individually to see if the developer has specifically set `installLocation="internalOnly"` or if they've simply left out it at all to determine whether it is intentional or not.

Comment: But I often see many apps that don't are any of those things. And they don't allow moving to the sd card, why they would do that? What type of advantage/benefit could that give.

Comment: Also per the documentation " By default, the system will not allow your application to install on the external storage, so you don't need to worry about your existing applications." - they might not have changed the default.

Comment: I think that @ianhanniballake has the correct answer here - most devs probably don't even think about it, if they are even aware of this permission, so most don't add a configuration for it at all. And, of course the default is to not allow it.

Comment: Yes that is why I put **allow**, because by default it isn't allowed.

Comment: If you decompile the apps you are looking at, you might find if the developer has set `installLocation="internalOnly"` - in those cases, you'd need to ask that developer why they 'haven't allowed' installing their app on external storage (usually, it will be one of the reasons listed above). If they haven't defined it at all, they are simply unaware and have not made any effort to specifically disallow it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake If you add that to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: I added an extra paragraph to talk about the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the main reason (and possibly the only reason) is because the phone might not have much internal storage. So this way the phone can utilise external storage to allow the user to install more apps when the internal storage is full. I'm assuming you've read the following document. It doesn't mention this answer but I think that's the reason why it exists.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

**Edit**: I think there are quite a few low end devices where the internal storage is very low compared to external storage.

**Edit 2**: The why not do this is because all the data on external storage is world readable. So if you're app stores data it can be taken out and read on some other device. Depending on the application you may not want to allow this.

Comment: But what about the "why not".

Comment: Well I didn't copy and paste from the link I posted, but I put the "why". The other answer only says why not. Also, I posted first (I just didn't put the content from the link because I wasn't sure if you read it or not - lesson learned for future answers). So many answers with no response.